# How do I calculate the Unit Normal of a Vector?

Tags: vectors, mathematical-physics

I'm trying to write a small function in C++ that calculates the Unit Normal of a Vector, however I'm stuck with the formula to do so as I feel like I'm missing out on something.

Let's say I have a point in 3D space: `(2.0, 3.0, 6.0)`

I will be using the formula **a** = d**n**

To calculate `d` I use `d = |a| = √2.0² + 3.0² + 3.0² = 7.0`

then we have **n** = 1/d

So **n** = 1/7.0, and d**n** = 1 (d**n** equals a magnitude of 1)

This is how I think I'm meant to calculate the Unit Normal of the vector, is this correct? Is the value of `dn` my answer, or is there another step?

Comment: What is it normal to?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by unit $\textbf{normal}$ of a vector. Are you trying to find a vector orthogonal to the given vector, which has unit length? My confusion is because there are infinitely many ways to do this (infinitely many orthogonal vectors to a given vector).

Comment: I'm not sure if my professor means unit normal vector or just the *unit vector*. The formula is meant to give you a vector that goes in a particular direction that has a magnitude of 1.

Comment: That’s just a unit vector.

Comment: If it's just a unit vector, you find $\vec n $ as $\frac{1}{|a|}\vec a $